# Gravity right circle drawable by using xml

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I am trying to achieve drawable to looks like this:

[image: gravity right circle]

I use this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:gravity="end">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval"
        >
        <size
            android:width="@dimen/bullet_size"
            android:height="@dimen/bullet_size"
            />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

But got this:

[image: result]

Any ideas what could be wrong?

I am using the gravity right circle dralable as follows:

```
textView.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.right_shspe);
```

Comment: Can you provide the XML of your layout file? You might used `ImageView` with wrong parameters.

Comment: I am using xml drawable as backgound

Comment: Please edit question and code of XML layout which includes your shape here.

Comment: You can use an ImageView and use shape as its `android:src` property. This way shape aspect ratio will not change and kept like what you defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should center the item which is holding the oval shape vertical and everything will be OK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:gravity="end|center_vertical">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval"
        >
        <size
            android:width="@dimen/bullet_size"
            android:height="@dimen/bullet_size"
            />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Done! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Change The Width and height accordingly and it will fix the shape

Comment: Width and height are the same value 10dp

Comment: There might be some issues with it Try Rebuiding your project

Comment: In mine it is working fine . A circle is shown There is problem with your project

Comment: Check the dimensions file

Comment: <dimen name="bullet_size">10dp</dimen>

Comment: try hardcoding values